# Nginx: proxy_pass ignored

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have these server blocks:

```
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name cloud.example.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/certs/cloud.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/private/cloud.example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/cloud.log;
        client_max_body_size 300m;
    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass          https://cloud.example.com;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }
  }
```

and

```
server {

    listen 886;
    server_name newcloud.example.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/certs/cloud.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/private/cloud.example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/newcloud.log;
        client_max_body_size 300m;
    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:4443;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }
  }
```

The problem is when I try https://newcloud.example.com:886 is proxied to cloud.example.com (which is on other machine). It never goes to 127.0.0.1 port 4443

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where have you added these `server` blocks exactly?

Comment: In separates files in /etc/nginx/sites-available and symlinked from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

Comment: When you run `nginx -T`, do you see these blocks in the output?